# Replicate values in a column using Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a specific problem and needs to be solved using *Scala*/*SPARK*.

I have a column in a `Dataframe` as shown below

```
ColA  

Tag1  
Tag2  
Tag3  
Tag1  
Tag2  
Tag3  
Tag1  
Tag2  
Tag3
```

Now I want to include a new column in the `dataframe` as shown below in the required format.

```
ColA  ColB   

Tag1  1    
Tag2  1  
Tag3  1  
Tag1  2  
Tag2  2  
Tag3  2  
Tag1  3  
Tag2  3  
Tag3  3
```

Can this be done in *Scala*/*Spark*. I am newbie in *Scala*/*Spark* and really stuck with it for a long time now. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Solution:

```
df.groupBy("ColA").agg(collect_list("ColA").alias("tmp"))
  .select(posexplode($"tmp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Window` function (`row_number()`) to generate `ColB` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ColA").orderBy("ColA")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("ColB", row_number().over(windowSpec)).show(false)
```

You should have the following output

```
+----+----+
|ColA|ColB|
+----+----+
|Tag1|1   |
|Tag1|2   |
|Tag1|3   |
|Tag3|1   |
|Tag3|2   |
|Tag3|3   |
|Tag2|1   |
|Tag2|2   |
|Tag2|3   |
+----+----+
```

Comment: my pleasure :) don't forget to upvote when you would be eligible

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tab")

val q = """
SELECT ColA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColA) as ColB
FROM tab
ORDER BY ColB, ColA
"""

val res = spark.sql(q)
```

Result:

```
scala> res.show
+----+----+
|ColA|ColB|
+----+----+
|Tag1|   1|
|Tag2|   1|
|Tag3|   1|
|Tag1|   2|
|Tag2|   2|
|Tag3|   2|
|Tag1|   3|
|Tag2|   3|
|Tag3|   3|
+----+----+
```